# Akka with Remote Actors and Durable mailboxes

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I would like configure Akka to use remote actors with redis durable mailbox, like below.

common.conf file:

```
 akka {
     actor {
         mailbox {
             redis {
                hostname = "127.0.0.1"
                port = 6379
              }
         }
     provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"   }

   remote {netty {hostname = "127.0.0.1" }}
}
```

and my application.conf file:

```
calculatorActor {include "common"}
remotecreation {
include "common"
akka {
    actor {
      deployment {
        /advancedCalculator {
          router = "round-robin"
          nr-of-instances = 200
          target {
            nodes = ["akka://CalculatorApplication@127.0.0.1:2552"]
          }

        }
      }
    }
    remote.netty.port = 2554
  }
}
```

This is configuration is derived from akka-sample-remote. When I run the application, I don't see any connections ever made to the redis side (durable mailbox!). Redis logs only contains:

```
0 clients connected (0 slaves)
```

Comment: Just a quick question since you've already asked this. Do the two remote actors, given they have same name, share the mailbox if they're using the same redis instance?

Answer (score 5):

You must specify a dispatcher with the correct mailbox type.

from the docs:

```
my-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = akka.actor.mailbox.RedisBasedMailboxType
}
```

and then create your actor with this dispatcher:

```
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"), name = "myactor")
```